# QRect on a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qrect

This seems trivial, but I didn't found a solution. All I want to do is to set up a coordinate system a QGraphicsScene [-10, -10] to [10, 10] (f.e. with setSceneRect(-10, -10, 20, 20)) and to plot a QRect within the scene, using the coordinate system of the scene.

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(-10.0, -10.0, 20.0, 20.0, ui->graphicsView);
// scene is already a QGraphicsScene pointer defined in the .h
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
scene->addRect(-8, -8, 4, 4);
```

What I am expecting in the example is a rectangle bounding at the left-bottom border. I also tried mapToScene() and fitInView(), but that also didn't brought me the expected result.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [QGraphicsView::setSceneRect()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) which tells the view what part of the scene to display.

Comment: Hello Steffen. I also tried setSceneRect() of QGraphicsView. But as the documentation states: "If unset, or if a null QRectF is set, this property has the same value as QGraphicsScene::sceneRect, and it changes with QGraphicsScene::sceneRect." If I display current values for sceneRect() (with qDebug() << scene->sceneRect(); )  I do get the same and correct values for both, QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, I just tried your example and up to now the only combination that is working for me is: fitInView() somewhen after construction (button handler for example) + setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate). FWIW adding a Rectangle at (-10,-10,20,20) seems to help, too.

Comment: Sorry, could you please provide a code snippet, since I don't get it to work correctly. EDIT: I can remember that when I used fitInView(), it was just a zoom-view of that specific area, but does not set the dimensions of the scene. As a result, the lines of the rectangles were > 1 px (because of the zoom) and there were scrollbars generated (which I don't need).

Comment: I set up a project (Qt Gui Application), added a QGraphicsView and a QButton to the UI, put your code in the constructor of MainWindow and added a click handler for the button:

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->graphicsView->fitInView(-10.0,-10.0,20.0,20.0);
}
Then after pressing the button, the view looks as I would expect.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. That also worked here as I wanted, but why do you need the pushButton? I tried ui->graphicsView->fitInView(-10.0,-10.0,20.0,20.0); in the constructor, just after creating the rectangle, but that doesn't work?!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly why the behaviour is like that. It might be a bug or just related to the fact that the event loop has to run before the view setup really takes place?!